# Locking all cells except below B5 and C5

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to lock all of a worksheet except cells in B and C below B4 and C4. When I run what I have, the desired cells are not unlocked and everything is protected. Also, is there a way to lock the header?

```
Sub UnlockColumns()
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Worksheets("Template").Activate
Worksheets("template").Unprotect Password:="word"
Worksheets("template").Range("B1", "C4").Select
Selection.Locked = False
Worksheets("template").Protect Password:="word"
End Sub
```

Comment: You're unlocking B1:C4 ?  That's not "cells in B and C below B4 and C4"

Comment: Yeah, this was from troubleshooting so I realized after I posted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
Sub UnlockColumns()
    Const PW As String = "word" 'use Const for fixed values
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template")
        .Unprotect Password:=PW
        .Range("B5:C100").Locked = False
        .Protect Password:=PW
    End With
End Sub
```

Typically there's no need to Select/Activate objects to work with them.

Comment: That is good to know. I think I have changed some setting on my workbook that is preventing things from working. I tried this on mine and it didn't work. All the cells were still locked. However, in a brand-new book, it works.